# Is there a upper limit on stack frame size

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

We have an out of memory error for a heap but ( just asking out of curiosity ) is there an equivalent limit on size of an individual stack ? If not then what prevents such an overflow if excess memory is needed by a stack frame ( like thousands of local variable etc ) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a thread requests more stack space than it has available it receives a StackOverflowError.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html

The size of an individual stack frame is determined at compile time and stored in the class file together with the method's code. Actually there are two fields: the size of the local variable array, and the depth of the operand stack. Both are limited to 2^16-1. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#1546

Comment: I guess stack overflow happens when the `number of stack frames` are more. I am talking about an `individual stack` using a lot of space

Comment: A stack overflow happens when the space left on stack is less than the space needed; not all stack frames are the same size. There is a limit on the number of local variables imposed by the class file specification; if you go over that limit it would be a compile time error. The size of stack frame is computed by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The space allocated to the runtime stack is for all of your stack frames on a single execution thread combined, i think.

The default size is different for most OSes. Have a look at these docs. You can increase the size if need be with the `-Xss` JVM parameter.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

Answer (score 0):

Each thread gets its own allocation of stack space.  You can set how big this allocation is with the -Xss option on the Java command line; the default is different on different platforms, but it's always a "per thread" amount.

The limit is an amount of memory per thread, not a number of entries on the stack.

Comment: Arrays are stored on the heap, not on the stack.

Comment: Hmm, yes, you're absolutely right.  I don't know what I was thinking.  I'll remove that last sentence.